# Password expiry notification script

Tags: python, beginner, ldap

I've just solve one problem that notifies users if their password is going to expire in 14 days.  The script is working fine. I just want to improve my code and desire some suggestions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Author :- Rahul Patil<linuxian.com>
# 

import sys
import os

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# Provide Ldap DN Details to Perform Ldap Search using anonymouse
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
Domain = 'linuxian.com'
EmailDomain = 'abc.om' # if your mail domain is different this will becom user@abc.com 
ConnectDC = 'ldap://localhost:389'
# if 14 days remains to expire password then it will send email to that user 
# until user update the new password
PwdWarnDays = 14
pwdMaxAge = 45 # default password expire in 45 days as per ldap ppolicy  

Subject = "Ldap Password Expiry Details"

MsgBody = """
Dear %s,
    Your Password Will be Expire in %s, we request you to please
change your password, your last password change date is %s

Best Regards,
Linux Admin
"""


def GetUserDetails():
        """ This Function Will save all details in file
        it will use ldap search query for the same."""
        # Create bind dn eg. dc=example,dc=com
        BindDN = ','.join([ 'dc=' + d for d in Domain.split('.') ])
        #
        import ldap 
        l = ldap.initialize(ConnectDC)
        # Perform Ldap Search
        return  l.search_s(
                BindDN,
                ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                '(uid=*)',['uid','pwdChangedTime']
            )


def CheckExpiry():
        """ 
        This Function will Check each user ExpiryWarning
        if it more thans WarningDays then it will send Emails
        to that particuler user
        """
         import datetime
         for k,v in Users:
                    uid = ''.join(v['uid'])
                    if 'pwdChangedTime' not in v:
                            pass
                            #print "User " + uid + "  not Updated Password" 
                    try:
                          l = ''.join(v['pwdChangedTime'])
                    except:
                            pass

                    if 'pwdChangedTime' in v:
                        # To extrace year month day
                        d1 = datetime.date.today()
                        d2 = datetime.date(int(l[0:4]),int(l[4:6]),int(l[6:8]))
                        DaysOfPasswordChange = (d1 - d2).days
                        d2 = d2.strftime('%d, %b %Y')

                        ExpireIn = pwdMaxAge - DaysOfPasswordChange

                        # if password not changed before 14 days 
                        if ExpireIn <= PwdWarnDays:
                            SendMail = "echo '" + MsgBody % (uid,ExpireIn,d2) + "' \
                                      mail -s " + '"' + Subject + '"' + ' ' + \
                                      uid + '@' + EmailDomain 
                            #os.system(SendMail)
                            print SendMail



if __name__ == '__main__':
        Users = GetUserDetails()
        CheckExpiry()
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm just going to comment on these three lines:

```
SendMail = "echo '" + MsgBody % (uid,ExpireIn,d2) + "' \
          mail -s " + '"' + Subject + '"' + ' ' + \
          uid + '@' + EmailDomain 
#os.system(SendMail)
print SendMail
```

1. *This doesn't work!* You've commented out the line that sends the e-mail. Now, I understand that you did this so that you can test the script without spamming your users with these messages, and that you intend to uncomment the line when you deploy the script. But this isn't the best approach.

   The first problem is that the need to test the script will come up again after you deploy it — you'll need to revise the text of the messages or change some other aspect the way it works, and then you'll want to test it again. So it would be worth your while to build in a permanent testing mechanism that's better than commenting out a line.

   The second problem is that just printing the `mail` command doesn't actually constitute a test. You have to read the output in order to check that it's correct, and you could easily miss a problem.

   What I suggest is that you have a setting that can be turned on and off to indicate whether the script is in testing or deployment:

   ```
   deployed = False           # Is script deployed?
   test_uid = 'rahul.patil'   # Send e-mail to this user if not deployed.
   ```

   and that you send the e-mail to the test user when testing:

   ```
   if not deployed:
       uid = test_uid
   SendMail = "echo '" + MsgBody % (uid,ExpireIn,d2) + "' \
             mail -s " + '"' + Subject + '"' + ' ' + \
             uid + '@' + EmailDomain 
   os.system(SendMail)
   ```

   Ideally you would provide a way to set the `deployed` flag (and the `test_uid`) through the script's command-line interface — see the [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module for one approach to doing this.
2. When you run a command using [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system), the command gets interpreted by the shell. This is risky, because the shell has complicated quoting and evaluation rules that you may not understand. For example, suppose that you edited `MsgBody` like this:

   ```
   MsgBody = """
   Dear %s,
        Your password will expire in %s day(s). We're sorry for the
   inconvenience, but we need you to change your password by %s.
   """
   ```

   Looks good, right? But if you actually try this, you'll find that the call to `os.system` fails with an error like this:

   ```
   sh: line 3: inconvenience,: command not found
   sh: -c: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
   sh: -c: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
   ```

   That's because the single quote in `We're` was interpreted by the shell as terminating the argument to `echo`.

   In order to avoid problems like this (where data gets wrongly interpreted as code by the shell), you should avoid passing the arguments to the shell. Instead of `os.system`, you should use the functions in the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. For example, like this:

   ```
   import subprocess

   p = subprocess.Popen(['mail', '-s', Subject, uid + '@' + EmailDomain],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
   p.communicate(MsgBody % (uid, ExpireIn, d2))
   ```

Comment: thanks for your reply , it is useful, but I want to say that mail command is working without any issue, I have tested.. may be because of my Luck :P

Comment: That's fine for now, but what about later, after you or some other developer makes a change?

Comment: Better yet, send mail using a [library call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) instead of a shell command.

Comment: @200_success: I did consider that, but it's not all that compelling in a simple case like this one. (A couple of lines with `subprocess` versus eight lines with `email` and `smtplib`.)

Comment: @GarethRees I'm adopting your suggestion into my code, that's working, can you please help me with print that mail command on terminal

Answer (score 4):

You should read through the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You code does not follow the naming conventions most Python code uses.

---

Single letter variables should be used sparingly because they might not be as intuitive as you think. A more descriptive name is better.

---

Imports should generally be done at the top of the file.

---

[`string.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) would likely me more readable than the string concatenation you are doing at the end of `CheckExpiry()`.

---

Your docstrings start with "This Function Will". This is unnecessary since documentation will always be describing what the function does.

---

At the beginning of your script, you define constants that set the date boundaries. This is good. However, you then repeatably use the value in comments. This is bad because if the policy changes to warn at 21 days, the comments need to be updated in addition to the constant's value.

---

You don't need a comment for every operation. In general, comments are better at saying **why** you are doing something, not saying **what** you are doing.

```
# if password not changed before 14 days 
if ExpireIn <= PwdWarnDays:
```

You have good variable names, so this line of code explains itself, the comment doesn't add anything. If you have a line of code that is complicated enough that you feel you need to document **what** it is doing, this is an indication that there *might* be a better way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much.., Amazing answer, I will follow that

Answer (score 2):

I would add "bind_s" to connect to ldap with a user

```
user_dn = 'someuser'
user_pwd = 'somepassword'
l = ldap.initialize(ConnectDC)
l.bind_s(user_dn, user_pwd) #LDAP admin would not allow to query pwdChangedTime as anonymous
```

and change some code to make it more beautiful when sending mail:

```
return l.search_s(bind_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(uid=*)', ['displayName', 'pwdChangedTime', 'uid'])

for k, v in Users:
    uid = ''.join(v['uid'])
    if 'displayName' in v:
        displayname = ''.join(v['displayName'])
    else:
        displayname = uid
...
if 'pwdChangedTime' in v:
...
else:
    d2 = '[You have not changed your password since account created]'
...
print mail_body % (displayname, pwd_expire_in_days, d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the function definitions from the script functionality with `if __name__ == '__main__':` as is customary for Python.  Also I would have `CheckExpiry()` take "Users" as an argument and return a list of expired users (or a tuple of name and e-mail address for each).  So that would read more like:

```
#!python
# ....
if __name__ == '__main__':
    userdata = GetUserDetails()
    expired = CheckExpiry(userdata)
# ...
```

From there I'd create a template (perhaps as simple as one using [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings) from the Python standard libraries, or possibly using something like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) ... and use it to generate the messages to each user.

If you really want to get fancy you could track the number of warnings you've sent to each user, perhaps in a very simple local flat file database using [SQLite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) (also from the standard library).